# httpd commands in cmd not working with Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

Everyone says you install Apache as a service by running:

```
httpd.exe -n "servicenameherexd"
```

But `cmd` outputs this:

```
'httpd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm looking for other ways to do this or how to fix this method. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is likely occurring because `httpd.exe` isn't in your Windows PATH/Path variable(s).

To install a current version of Apache (i.e. Apache 2.4.x) as a service on Windows:

1. Navigate as an Administrator to the folder where `httpd.exe` resides (typically under the `bin` folder of your primary Apache installation). To do this:

   - Open the *Run...* dialog box under the Windows Start menu and type *cmd --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>*. This will open an administrative command window (i.e with a UAC prompt).
   - Use ex. `cd c:\path\to\Apache\bin` to navigate to your Apache installation `bin` folder.
2. Run ex. `httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache2.4"` to install Apache as a Windows service.

You can then use ex. `httpd.exe -k start -n "Apache2.4"` to start the Apache service once it is installed (as needed) from the same window.

*Caveats*

- To avoid issues, you should always use `Apach2.4` as the service name unless you have a compelling reason not to.
- You may need to stop any prior Apache service with ex. `httpd.exe -k stop -n "Apache2.4"`.
- You should be able to uninstall an Apache service with ex. `httpd.exe -k uninstall -n "Apache2.4"`.

For further information, see [Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html).